# What is a LDAP standard for sAMAccountName?

Tags: security, c#-4.0, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I have an attribute `samaccountname` which I am able to retrieve for a user.

However, `samaccount` name is AD specific and need LDAP standard attribute. For example, in a query, if I am using

```
(&(objectCategory=Group)(CN=MemberName))
```

then it is also AD specific and needs to be replaced by

```
(&(objectClass=Group)(CN=MemberName))
```

as `objectClass` is standard LDAP attribute.

Can you please suggest the LDAP standard attribute for `sAMAccountName`?

Comment: There is no "generic" LDAP equivalent for `samAccountName` since that attributes is very much Windows-/AD-specific and does not correspond to any "generic" attribute

Comment: Ok, is uid can be used in place of samaccountname? as according to RNC ldap wiki, uid can be used.

Answer (score 4):

[sAMAccountName](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/SamAccountName) is a LDAP standard attribute defined with the OID: 1.2.840.113556.1.4.221 with a Syntax of 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15 ( Case-insensitive UTF-8 (Unicode) String)

However, Microsoft Active Directory implements several "Rules" which are not consistent on even all versions of Microsoft Active Directory and which may be hard to implement a server-side "Rules"

As @marc_s pointed out there is no commonly implemented attributes within LDAP Objectclasses like inetOrgPerson.

Comment: Ok. I think UID is standard LDAP attribute? but i am not sure that it is used instead of samaccountname?

Comment: @sagaryadwad, if you found a solution to equivalent LDAP attribute into AD `sAMAAccountName` and if you can share, I would appreciate it.